# How to fix: FilesBrowse() triggers Event even if File has not been Uploaded (PySimpleGUI)

Tags: python, user-interface, file-upload, pysimplegui

**Goal**:

I'm trying to design a GUI with PySimpleGUI.

**Situation**:

FilesBrowse() allows the user to upload multiple files at the same time. This is functional; however, if the user tries to re-upload new files by clicking the "Browse" button again, but then cancels it and does not select any file, then the event seems to capture the last file that was previously selected.

For example, suppose that in the first iteration, the files *file1*, *file2*, and *file3* are selected and submitted, and the subsequent code is executed. Now, suppose that the user clicks 'browse' again to upload another file, but regrets it and does not upload anything eventually. In this case, the list containing the values of the *event* will have file1, file2, *file3*, ***file3*** (although it should be *file1*, *file2*, *file3* only).

I have "enable_events" set to `True`, and this is the part of the code where I'm gathering the values of files:

```
if event == "_key_":
  file_of_key = values["_key_"]
  # if at least one file has been uploaded:
  if file_of_key:
  # list containing the the files uploaded
    files_of_key += file_of_key.split(";")
```

How could I go about debugging and fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how you use `sg.FileBrowse`.

1. Most of time, it work with an previous element `sg.Input` and `Cancel` button when select files means not to change the content of `sg.Input`, and another button to confirm or send the selection stored in `sg.Input`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

layout = [
    [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-'), sg.FilesBrowse()],
    [sg.Button('OK')]
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

2. Another case, using a button to invoke `sg.popup_get_file` and update selected files somewhere by yourself.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))

layout = [
    [sg.Input(disabled=True, key='-INPUT-'), sg.Button('Browse')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Browse':
        files = sg.popup_get_file('', multiple_files=True, no_window=True)
        if files:
            window['-INPUT-'].update(';'.join(files))
        else:
             window['-INPUT-'].update('')

window.close()
```